# Processing large image volumes

Tags: opengl, image-processing, 3d, large-data-volumes, volume-rendering

I have a huge 3D volume, which sizes above 2GB. I want to load this data, process it and display in my application as a 3D volume, in which zooming and rotation of volume cn be performed.

I saw applications which loads this huge data and displays it.

My doubt is that, Windows32 bit applications address space is limited to 2GB, then what is the technique used inside these applications to handle this huge volume?

or

How can i mange these huge data in my application with optimal performance?

Answer (score 3):

> My doubt is that, Windows32 bit applications address space is limited to 2GB

Only on 32 bit systems.

> then what is the technique used inside these applications to handle this huge volume?

Using a 64 bit system, which gives you an address space of 2<sup>34</sup> GiB. However the real bottleneck is the size of texture space on modern GPUs. I for example am doing such medical volume rendering and even with 2 GiB GPU memory your textures are limited to some 1.5 GiB as you still need some space for the screen framebuffer and other resources.

> How can i mange these huge data in my application with optimal performance?

Use a 64 bit system. You will of course also need those amounts of system memory (RAM). For example my <s>toy</s> workstation has 64 GiB of memory.